# Doctrine2 - how to delete all records remove records by ids from array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Is there any better way to remove records by ids that are in php array ?
Below is my code (zf2 controller action) , but I think it is not good way...

// $_POST['id'] = "1,5,6,82,99"

```
 public function deleteAllAction() {

        $array = explode(",", $this->getRequest()->getPost('id'));

        foreach ($array as $id) {
            $feature = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Product\Entity\Feature', $id);
            if ($feature) {
                $this->getEntityManager()->remove($feature);
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            }
        }

        return new JsonModel(array("success"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly better way with [querying Doctrine repository](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) to get all entities first and then removing them. Check out your modified code below:

```
public function deleteAllAction() {
    $array = explode(",", $this->getRequest()->getPost('id'));

    $features = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Product\Entity\Feature')->findBy( array( 'id' => $array ) );

    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($feature);
    }

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

    return new JsonModel(array("success"));
}
```